# Which GPU should I use on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gpu, nvidia, gcloud-compute

Right now, I'm working on my master's thesis and I need to train a huge Transformer model on GCP. And the fastest way to train deep learning models is to use GPU. So, I was wondering **which GPU should I use among the ones provided by GCP?** The ones available at the current moment are:

- NVIDIA® A100
- NVIDIA® T4
- NVIDIA® V100
- NVIDIA® P100
- NVIDIA® P4
- NVIDIA® K80

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It all depends on what are the characteristics you're looking for.

First, let's collect some information about these different GPU models and see which one suits you best. You can google each model's name and see its characteristics. I did that and I created the following table:

| Model | FP32 (TFLOPS) | Price | TFLOPS/dollar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nvidia A100 | 19.5 | 2.933908 | 6.646425178 |
| Nvidia Tesla T4 | 8.1 | 0.35 | 23.14285714 |
| Nvidia Tesla P4 | 5.5 | 0.6 | 9.166666667 |
| Nvidia Tesla V100 | 14 | 2.48 | 5.64516129 |
| Nvidia Tesla P100 | 9.3 | 1.46 | 6.369863014 |
| Nvidia Tesla K80 | 8.73 | 0.45 | 19.4 |

In the previous table, you see can the:

- `FP32`: which stands for **32-bit floating point** which is a measure of how fast this GPU card with single-precision floating-point operations. It's measured in **TFLOPS** or **Tera Floating-Point Operations*... The higher, the better.
- `Price`: Hourly-price on GCP.
- `TFLOPS/Price`: simply how much operations you will get for one dollar.

From this table, you can see:

- `Nvidia A100` is the fastest.
- `Nvidia Tesla P4` is the slowest.
- `Nvidia A100` is the most expensive.
- `Nvidia Tesla T4` is the cheapest.
- `Nvidia Tesla T4` has the highest operations per dollar.
- `Nvidia Tesla V100` has the lowest operations per dollar.

And you can observe that clearly in the following figure:

[image]

I hope that was helpful!

Comment: TL;DR : A100 GPUs are great if you can afford them. Otherwise, T4 GPUs offer the best bang for buck.

Comment: Where are A100 available? I looked at the US data centers at https://cloud.google.com/compute/gpus-pricing and I don't see it listed. But I know they exist

Comment: @CsabaToth, I know I'm 4 months late, but here are the available zones **in US** for A100 from [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones): `us-central1-a`, `us-central1-b`, `us-central1-c`, `us-central1-f`, `us-east1-b`, `us-east4-c`, `us-east5-b`, `us-west1-b`, `us-west3-b`, and `us-west4-b`.

Comment: Here is a source for the GPU performances: 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus#performance_comparison_chart

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia says that using the most modern, powerful GPUs is not only faster, it also ends up being cheaper: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/saving-time-and-money-in-the-cloud-with-the-latest-nvidia-powered-instances/

Google came to a similar conclusion (this was a couple of years ago before the A100 was available): https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/your-ml-workloads-cheaper-and-faster-with-the-latest-gpus

I guess you could make an argument that both Nvidia and Google could be a little biased in making that judgement, but they are also well placed to answer the question and I see no reason not to trust them.

Comment: The first article only compares A100 to V100.

The second article does show how inefficient the k80 is, but also mentions that the T4 is ideal for many use-cases.

From reading those articles, I couldn't conclude that the most modern and powerful GPUs are necessarily the cheapest. If you're willing to wait, the T4 seems to be the most cost-efficient option by a large margin.